# Kubernetes nodeSelector not working in pods, replication controllers and deployments

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set node affinity using nodeSelector as discussed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/

However, no matter if I use a Pod, a Replication Controller or a Deployment, I can't get the kubectl create to work properly. This is the error I get, and it happens with everything similarly:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "test-pod.yaml": Pod in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: [pos 222]: json: expect char '"' but got char 't'

Substitute "Deployment" or "ReplicationController" for "Pod" and it's the same error everywhere. Here is my yaml file for the test pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    ingress: yes
```

If I remove the nodeSelector part of the file, the pod builds successfully. This also works with Deployments and Replication Controllers as well. I made sure that the proper label was added to the node.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It could be the term you are using here. Assume when creating a config that keys used in another context are reserved. Call it *myIngress* and see what happens.

Comment: Ah yes. Got bit by the same thing when I accidentally left a `true` in there (unquoted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In yaml, the token `yes` evaluates to a boolean `true` (http://yaml.org/type/bool.html)

Internally, `kubectl` converts yaml to json as a preprocessing step. Your node selector is converting to `"nodeSelector":{"ingress":true}`, which fails when trying to decode into a string-to-string map.

You can quote the string like this to force it to be treated as a string: 
`ingress: "yes"`